# Determining water movement in Cells with Same DPD

Tags: botany, physiology

A cell has OP=10bars and TP =5bars .other cell has OP =15 bars and TP =10bars. DPD of both is same ie.5bars. So how do we determine in which direction water will move?

OP is osmotic pressure. TP is turgor pressure. DPD is Dossusion Pressure Deficient.

Comment: Please type the full form of those abbreviations.

Comment: @JM97 Done. All Full Forms Added.